# Elasticsearch - return document count by date - in date order

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have the following to return a count of documents 'grouped' by the document date. However, I would like the results to be displayed in date order. I tried the 'sort' option but this doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions ?

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    size: 0,
    sort: {
        date: {
            order: "desc"   
        }
    },
    aggs: {
        "docs_by_date": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "date",
                "size": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort `buckets` use following query:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
size: 0,

aggs: {
    "docs_by_date": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "date",
            "size": 0,
            "order" : { "_term" : "asc" }
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) for more info